# Why is PHP $_SESSION not working on other pages?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I was trying the "$_SESSION" function, but it didn't work. Here are the codes.

test1.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['testid']= "12";
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['testid']; ?></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The output was:

```
    12
```

test2.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['testid']; ?></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The output was nothing.

So, what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe your privacy settings in your browser

Comment: Make sure you have no output what so ever before the opening tag in `<?php session_start();`, no space, new line or anything. Also make sure that you show [all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) while developing.

Comment: Also make sure the files aren't stored as UTF-8 with BOM, but only as ordinary UTF-8 files.

Comment: @magnus. Thanks for the info, it seems it's only work in codeigniter. I'll delete my comment

Comment: @GodyaAditya - Ah, yes. Frameworks usually have their own session implementations that can be disrupted by manually calling session_start().